# How can i write a datatable content on web page in XMl foramte in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml

How can i write a datatable content on web page in XMl foramte in asp.net?
i also need to customize the datatable before writing to web page.
Edited:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("XML");
        String email = EmailAddress.Text.ToString();
        dt.Load(obj.GetXML("XYZ@gmail.com"));
//now i want this dt to dosplayed in the XMl form on the same page, how can i achieve this?
        'XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        'XmlTextReader xr=new XmlTextReader( 
        'WriteGoogleMap(dt.ToString(), Response.OutputStream);
        'Response.End();
        //System.Xml.
    }
```

Comment: not sure to understand what you want... Do you want to produce an xml file which content is extracted from a DB ? in this case, what do you mean by "customize the datatable"

Comment: i have got some data in datatable which i need to  display on asp page in XMl form.

Comment: then what is the problem you encounter ?

Comment: I dont know how to display it in XMl form on the aspx page?

Comment: So you want to show xml data and not return data ?

Comment: i want to show XMl data which will be read by some third party, i dont know how they would read it. But for that i want to create that XMl that XMl will be read by some third party.

Comment: i Want to return data too, you know how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    public string GetXml(string urlBase)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        settings.Indent = true;
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, settings))
        {
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("urlset", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");

            // Repeat this code:
            writer.WriteStartElement("url");
            writer.WriteElementString("loc", "[your url]");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }

        return output.ToString();
    }
```

Then use the result to feed a label :

```
<script runat="server" type=text/C#>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myLabel.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(
            GetXml("http://www.dotnetperls.com/")    
        );
    }
</script>
```

[Edit]
I think you should start by the beginning. Do not mix all concepts in your single question. Spend time for learning the basics (read books, take courses, etc.). In your specific case, I suggest you to split the work in several layers:

- A data layer the is responsible to build a datatable
- A business or service layer, capable of creating the xml document from the databable
- A presentation layer that will contains :

  - a custom http handler (.ashx) that will return the xml
  - a visual page that can show the html representation of the Xml

good luck

Comment: Where is my datatable in use here?

Comment: can i pass dt instead of URl in the GetXMl ?

Answer (score 1):

DataTable has method named:

```
WriteXml
```